# add an element to the end of an array, deleting elements from the beginning to maintain the size?

Tags: javascript, arrays

There are variations on this question but none are quite what I'm looking for.

What is the **simplest** way in javascript to always add new elements to the end of an array ( my_array.push(x) )?

And if the array grows larger than a certain size (e.g. 100 elements) then shift elements backwards (my_array[1] becomes my_array[0]) in order to continue adding to the end of the array.

Comment: using array.shift() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`push` returns the length of the array, so you can use this to compare against the maximum desired length:

`if (a.push(x) > MAX_LENGTH) a.shift();`